# Trouble sending transport to remote server using Winston

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have been trying to implement centralized logging across several clustered servers. I am impressed with Winston, but have been running into a path issue. Need to know the syntax for accessing remote server (code snippet included below)

I am able to log to console, a local file and a rotating local file(s)...but when I try to send a transport over to a remote server, it gets lost in the ether.

```
const options = {
  file: {`enter code here`
    level: 'info',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/app.log`,
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: true,
    maxsize: 5242880,
    maxFiles: 5,
    colorize: true,
  },
  console: {
    level: 'debug',
    handleExceptions: true,
    json: false,
    colorize: true,
  },
  rotator:{
    frequency: '1m',
    filename: `${appRoot}/logs/application-%DATE%.log`,
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: '20k',
    maxFiles: '1d',
    level: 'info'
  },
  remoteServer:{
    level:'info',
    filename: '\\\\SERVERNAME.corp.COMPANY.com\\Filestore\\PM2_logs\\SM-`API-out.log'`
  },
};

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File(options.file),
    new winston.transports.Console(options.console),
    new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile(options.rotator),
    new winston.transports.File(options.remoteServer),
  ],
  exitOnError: false,
});
```

I expected a copy of the log output to go to the file at the end of the path, but no such luck as of yet. I have tried a variety of forward/backward slash syntax.